# Blowfish options in php

Tags: php, encryption, blowfish

I use PHP 5.3.3 and is trying to do a blowfish encryption with these options:

> The bytes of the encrypted data are hex-coded and left padded up to two characters with a zero. Blowfish ECB is used for encryption with a attached salt.

It's from an integration manual of EVO payments international (creditcard payments).

Can I use crypt()? (password_hash() is not available in 5.3)

Comment: Do you want *encryption* or *hashing*? I'll guess *encryption*, in which case `crypt` is (confusingly) not what you want.

Comment: The data should be encrypted, and decrypted by EVO. Can I use [mcrypt](http://tz1.php.net/manual/en/book.mcrypt.php)?

Comment: Yes, mcrypt should be it.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is looking for an answer to this, here is my solution:

```
$cipher = mcrypt_module_open(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, '', MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, '');
$iv = '12345678'; //this is ignored when using MCRYPT_MODE_ECB
mcrypt_generic_init($cipher, $blowfish_secret, $iv);
$data_blowfish = mcrypt_generic($cipher, $datastring_to_encrypt);
mcrypt_generic_deinit($cipher);
return bin2hex($data_blowfish);
```

It seems to work